# How to modify Shadowbox.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

i have a shadowbox script for a youtube video.

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>

<body>
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOyQasrgaMs" rel="shadowbox;height=640;width=620">My Movie</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem: 
The popup appear but the video dont start.

Modify the script:
**I need that the wideo start when the page load, there is a script able to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

Go to YouTube, click share -> embed below a video and append `autoplay=1` to the url.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mOyQasrgaMs?autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox;height=640;width=620">My Movie</a>
```

Comment: Now run! And you know how can start at page load?